# Factory in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, factory

i'm new in Dart. I came from Java and there someting I want to mimic.
I have a project that has multiple screens and each screen has multiple bodies.
For exemple:
Screen UMW0001
Body: 0001
Body: 0002
Body: 0003

I want to build those widgets according to the body.
I have a widget call BuildBody, today he's like this:

```
String body = autorization.getBody("UMW0001");

switch (body) {
  case '0002':
    return const detalhe_0002.Detalhe();
  default:
    return const detalhe_0001.Detalhe();
}
```

I would like to improve this by using some kind of factory to build the right body, something like

```
String body = "0002";

Widget widget = methodToCreateWidget("page/umw0001/$body");

return widget();
```

Is flutter capable of that?

Comment: Yes, you can use a static method or global function to return anything you want based on the input parameters.  You can also use a factory constructor to promise that anything returned is of a given class or any of its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with below code. Here i have taken the `buildBody` as an higher level function you can put it any class and make it static if you wish and can  do in the constructor too.

```
class Detalhe0001 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Detalhe0001({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('Detalhe 0001'),
    );
  }
}

class Detalhe0002 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Detalhe0002({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('Detalhe 0002'),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  String body = "0002";
  Widget widget = buildBody("page/umw0001/$body");

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: widget,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildBody(String body) {
  switch (body.split('/').last) {
    case '0002':
      return const Detalhe0002();
    default:
      return const Detalhe0001();
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt regarding this.